# symbols in .htaccess redirection issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having some issues with redirecting some pages with "%11" and "%28".

I'm trying to redirect a couple of pages, the rest work but I realized those with some symbols in it are not redirecting.

**For example:**

`Redirect 301 /cars/mercedes%11benz/ http://www.example.com/cars/mercedes-benz/`

`Redirect 301 /alfa-romeo/alfa-romeo-147-%282001%E2%80%932009%29-2008090174/ http://www.example.com/cars/alfa-romeo-147/`

do not work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically specifies that only ASCII text is allowed. Might u having white spaces in url. Please remove them.

As for mod_rewrite, I believe that you've got that right except that the dot character in the character range need not be escaped, i.e., the hyphen is properly located at the beginning and the space is escaped. The ü probably doesn't need to be escaped but it shouldn't hurt). As for browsers making the conversion, that's a "browser thing" which Apache understands (and converts internally to the correct character).

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^%?\ ]*\%
RewriteRule ^. http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^/cars/mercedes-benz/  http://www.test-site.com/cars/mercedes%11benz/ [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does the above code redirects the entire site or just the page? Sorry, i'm pretty new to these stuff. Do you mind showing me your method in regards to the two pages i've listed above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, i can't change the urls from the old site now. So is there a way to achieve the redirection? thanks

Comment: Hi thanks, i've tried the code but it still doesn't redirect. =(